# How to show view for submitted result of a webform by a user

Tags: views, webforms, users

How i can show all submitted value of a webform by a user in a view in a tab of a user profile section.

Iam using drupal 6.For example when user click on a tab say form on his profile the webform value submitted by that user show.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that in drupal 7 but not in drupal 6. In drupal 7, go to View.

1. Create a relationship "Webform Submissions: User" and require it
2. Create the contextual filter "User: uid"
3. Select the relationship which you created in step 2 and select "provide Default Value" under "When the value is NOT in the URL" and select "User ID from logged in User".

I hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link which is very usefull http://yalesites.yale.edu/book/creating-view-webform-data.